# ArrayList input complexity

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList Clothes = new ArrayList();  
ArrayList dictionary = new ArrayList(); dictionary.add(Clothes);
```

I can add to Clothes via

```
Clothes.add("hello, world");
```

But why can't I add to Clothes like this:

```
(dictionary.get(0)).add("hello, world");
```

?

Comment: you cannot get 0th element before you create/init it

Comment: .. or a cast `((ArrayList)(dictionary.get(0)))...`

Comment: @Lashane he did add it, it's just hidden on the right :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using raw `ArrayList`s.  Because of this, the `get` method returns an `Object`, and `Object`s don't have an `add` method.

Instead, use the generic form of `ArrayList`, passing type parameters to specify what objects each `ArrayList` can hold.

```
// holds Strings
ArrayList<String> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
// holds ArrayLists of Strings
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
```

The compiler will know that the `get` method on `dictionary` will return an `ArrayList<String>`, so that it can validate your call to `add`.

```
dictionary.get(0).add("hello, world");
```

As an aside, it's generally the best thing to code to the interface, which is `List` here:

```
// holds Strings
List<String> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
// holds Lists of Strings
List<List<String>> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: ahh okay. Thanks man- that worked :) I just needed the : ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 2):

You can but you need to specify the type of list elements.  See example below:

```
List<String> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
dictionary.add(clothes);
(dictionary.get(0)).add("hello, world");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `ArrayList` is a container of `Object`s and `(dictionary.get(0))` is therefore an `Object`, and `Object` doesn't have an `add()` method.

You have a couple of options. You can cast to `ArrayList` or just `List`:

```
((List)dictionary.get(0)).add("hello, world");
```

Or you can use generics

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use raw type `ArrayList`, go through the [Generics lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). Second, please follow Java naming convention and rename `Clothes` to `clothes`.

Now let's answer your actual question, when you do

```
dictionary.get(0)
```

what's the type of the returned object? It's of type `Object`, which doesn't have `add` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `dictionary` array does not have a type specified so when you do `dictionary.get(0)` it return type is `Object` and `Object` does not have `add()` method.

Just declare your arrays as follows:

```
List<String> clothes = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<List<String>> dictionary = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

and this should work:

```
clothes.add("hello, world");
(dictionary.get(0)).add("hello, world");
```